# Can I retreave a variable from mySQL database while I am doing UPDATE?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm running this query:

```
if($ModifiedInGoogle != $row['ModifiedInGoogle']) {
  // run update query
  mysql_query("UPDATE events 
                  SET EventName = '$EventName', 
                      StartDate = '$StartDate', 
                WHERE GoogleID = '$GoogleID' ");
```

If the `EventID` variable is not being changed in the `UPDATE`, is there a way I can get it and assign it to an `$EventID` variable here?

Comment: If you want it very badly, then a stored procedure might be [an option](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562467/sql-server-select-update-stored-procedure-weirdness).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. `UPDATE` queries are for putting data into the database. If you want to retrieve data, then you use a separate `SELECT` query.

Comment: True, but you could use two statements -- first to get the eventid value, and the second would be the `UPDATE` statement.  Oracle has the `RETURNING` syntax, but IIRC `OUTPUT` (a la SQL Server) is ANSI now...